# Help with OpportunityLineItems VF page

Tags: apex, visualforce, inline

I am trying to do inline editing on a vf page with a customController but I can't seem to get any data to pass to the controller on clicking on the save button.

VF Page:

```
<apex:form id="makeEdit">
    <apex:repeat var="oppProductInfo" value="{!oppLineItems}">
        <table id="lineItemTable">
            <tbody>
                <tr class="displayNone">
                    <td colspan="5">
                        <div class="twoColumns" style="height: 61px;">
                            <apex:outputLabel value="Version:" for="picklistHeader" />
                            <br />
                            <apex:outputfield value="{!oppProductInfo.Product2.Version__c}" styleClass="removeDefault picklistHeader" id="picklistHeader">
                            </apex:outputfield>
                        </div>
                        <div class="twoColumns">
                            <apex:outputLabel value="Term: # Years:" for="termYear"/>
                            <br />
                            <apex:outputfield value="{!oppProductInfo.Term_Years__c}" styleClass="removeDefault termYear" id="termYear">
                                <apex:inlineEditSupport showOnEdit="saveEdit, cancelEdit" event="ondblclick" changedStyleClass="myBoldClass" resetFunction="resetInlineEdit"/>
                            </apex:outputfield>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <apex:commandButton id="saveEdit" value="Save Changes" action="{!updateRecord}" rerender="makeEdit" status="updatingRecord" styleClass="newButton floatRight">
            <apex:param name="termYear" value="{!oppProductInfo.Term_Years__c}" assignTo="{!termYear}" />
        </apex:commandButton>
    </apex:repeat>
</apex:form>
```

Controller Code:

```
public String termYear { get; set; }
public PageReference updateRecord(){
    OpportunityLineItem pli = new OpportunityLineItem();
    pli.Id = curId;
    pli.Term_Years__c = termYear;

    try{
        update pli;
        System.debug('Update Successful');
    } catch (Exception e){
        System.debug(e.getMessage());
        ApexPages.Message msg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, e.getMessage());
        ApexPages.addMessage(msg);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Would someone mind pushing me in the right direction? I feel I might be doing something really stupid :/

Update:

I also debugged "termYear" to the console and it's just showing as the previous value

Answer (score 0):

To create a record you must create a new instance of it when your controller loads. Put the line `pli = new OpportunityLineItem();` inside your constructor and set `pli` as a getter/setter outside your methods. In your page, you can then reference the fields of `pli` directly (like `<apex:inputField value="{!pli.MyField__c}"/>`).

If you want to edit a record, I strongly recommend you to query for all the fields in your object in your constructor, and assign it to a public variable, with setter/getter attributes. Then, the rest is pretty much the same I explained above.

Also, I noticed you tried to build a table using HTML, but then, if you need a table for multiple values, consider using `<apex:dataTable>`. It is easier, in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks for this... I worked out I was being silly and lazy loading the Opp and Opp Line Items so it was just querying the data and updating it -_-